# How to convert a labelmap.prototxt into a set ? Caffe

Tags: python, dictionary, caffe

I have the **labelmap.prototxt** and I want to convert it into a set because I want to use it with Intel Neural Compute Stick SDK.

**Input**

**home/labelmap.prototxt**

```
item {
  name: "none_of_the_above"
  label: 0
  display_name: "background"
}
item {
  name: "1"
  label: 1
  display_name: "person"
}
item {
  name: "2"
  label: 2
  display_name: "bicycle"
}
item {
  name: "3"
  label: 3
  display_name: "car"
}
```

**Output:**

```
set(["background","person","bicycle","car"])
```

I tried as follow:

```
>>> with open('labelmap_coco.prototxt') as f:
...     d = literal_eval(f)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Answer (score 1):

Read about proto buffers, in caffe ssd proto file persist message LabelMap, so you can read object data from prototxt. It's very nice thing. 
Check out the code:

```
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format as tf

f = open('labelmap.prototxt', 'r')
lm = caffe_pb2.LabelMap()
lm = tf.Parse(f.read(), lm)
display_names = [x.display_name for x in lm.item]
```